# Is it possible to extract App Reviews from the google play store by countries?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Is it possible to extract app reviews from the google play store by countries? I know that this is possible for the apple app store but haven't seen any possibility for the google play store yet. Maybe someone knows how to find a way to see the country of origin for specific reviews and not only the language. 
Thank you!